# open file in python without file's full name?

Tags: python

I am trying to execute `f = open('filename')` in python.
However, I dont know the full name of the file. All I know is that it starts with 's12' and ends with '.ka',I know the folder where it's located, and I know it is the only file in that folder that starts and ends with "s12" and ".ka". Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 10):

Glob is your friend:

```
from glob import glob
filename = glob('s12*.ka')[0]
```

Careful though, glob returns a list of *all* files matching this pattern so you might want to assert that you get the file you actually want somehow.